# Assert the width of an image using React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, image, jestjs, react-testing-library

Say I have a simple image based component:

```
// ./Figure.js

const Figure = ({src}) => (
    <img
        src={src}
        width="100%"
    />
);
```

I want to test that its width is `100%`.

My test:

```
// ./Figure.test.js

import Figure from './Figure'
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'

describe('Figure', () => {
    const setup = () => {
        return render(
            <Figure
                src="https://src.com"
            />
        )
    }

    it('has the right width', () => {
        setup()

        const image = screen.getByAltText('alt')

        expect(image.src).toBe('https://src.com/')
        expect(image.width).toBe("100%")
    })
})
```

However, that gives me an error:

```
  ● Figure › renders

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "100%"
    Received: 0
```

Question: How can I assert the width of an image using React Testing Library without using snapshots?

Answer (score 11):

The most direct answer is to specify the 100% width definition as a CSS style rather than use the `width` attribute. The [HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dimension-attributes) indicates that `width` and `height` are meant to be "valid non-negative integers" representing the pixel dimensions of the resource; what you actually want is an image to fit its container, which is a CSS concern.

By doing this, you can now use [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) in your test to validate what you specified and that it's not overridden by anything else.

```
// ./Figure.js
const Figure = ({src}) => (
    <img
        src={src}
        style="width: 100%;"
    />
);

// ./Figure.test.js
it('has the right width', () => {
    setup()

    const image = screen.getByAltText('alt')

    expect(image.src).toBe('https://src.com/')
    expect(getComputedStyle(image).width).toBe("100%")
})
```

---

The extended answer is that Jest uses jsdom under the hood, which is essentially a mock browser written in javascript. It's meant to behave very similarly to a browser but is not exactly the same in order to be useful for testing.

I don't personally know all the boundaries of jsdom, though I do recall having issues testing anything related to dimensions or positioning. As a result, I tend to either not test those things explicitly (I prefer testing behaviour over presentation) or test them in a true headless browser, using for example either of [jest-electron-runner](https://github.com/facebook-atom/jest-electron-runner) or [Taiko](https://github.com/getgauge/taiko).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and like this worked fine for me:

```js
expect(image).toHaveAttribute("width", "100%")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've arrived at this answer looking for how to do this with width set by CSS, you can simply use `.toHaveStyle()` assertion provided by Testing Library's [jest-dom](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohavestyle)

```
// ./Figure.js

const Figure = ({src}) => (
    <img
        src={src}
        style="width: 24px;"
    />
);

// ./Figure.test.js
it('has the right width', () => {
    setup()

    const image = screen.getByAltText('alt')

    expect(image.src).toBe('https://src.com/')
    expect(image).toHaveStyle({ width: '24px'})
})
```